# Using PropertyBuilder.HasValueGenerator and Connecting to Database Context

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to be able to look up information in my database and generate a default value for one of my entity's fields based on the results.

Problem is, I don't know how to inject the EF context into the creation of the ValueGenerator.  The way I am doing it now requires a parameterless constructor.

Here's what I have so far.

In my DbContext OnModelCreating:

```
            entity.Property(e => e.SampleNumber)
                .HasColumnName("SampleNumber")
                .HasMaxLength(25)
                .HasValueGenerator<SampleIDGenerator>();
```

My ValueGenerator:

```
public class SampleIDGenerator : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    private readonly WellWaterEntities db;

    public SampleIDGenerator(WellWaterEntities context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    protected override object NextValue(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        string lastitem = db.Samples.OrderByDescending(x => x.SampleNumber)
            .FirstOrDefault().SampleNumber;

        if (lastitem != null)
        {
            int lastSequence;
            if (int.TryParse(lastitem.Substring(5, 4), out lastSequence))
            {
                return lastitem.Substring(0, 5) + (lastSequence + 1).ToString("0000");
            }
        }
        return DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + "0001";
    }
}
```

Comment: For what do you need a parameterless constructor? For the Generator-class or for the Context-class?

Comment: @Nikolaus The ValueGenerator.  The context throws an exception with an error message to this effect.  Obviously I can remove the constructor, but then how to I get to my configured db context?  I was thinking entry.Context might be the ticket.

Comment: You might think of a parameterless constructor in your Context-class, where you could do the configuration manually, which is also needed for migrations. Then you could initialize the context either in the constructor of the generator or just in time in the NextValue-Method. Maybe this could be a performance issue though. Have you tried entry.Context yet?

Comment: Yep entry.Context is working.  I will post an answer shortly.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NextValue() parameter `EntityEntry entry` is populated with `DbContext entry.Context`.

```
    protected override object NextValue(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        WellWaterEntities db = (WellWaterEntities) entry.Context;

        ...
    }
```